# react-boilerplate sagas for new route

Tags: reactjs, generator, react-router-redux, redux-saga, react-boilerplate

In the sample sagas of `react-boilerplate`, sagas are exported as an array:

```
export function* defaultSaga() {

}

export default [
  defaultSaga,
];
```

The default is then injected in `routes.js`:

```
...
injectSagas(sagas.default);
...
```

However, when I added a new route for authentication, I get an error that says **`saga argument must be a Generator function!`** even if I only have the default sagas (same as above).

I added the route to `routes.js`:

```
//routes.js
export function authRoutes(store) {
  //same code as createRoutes
}
```

And imported the function to create a new route for the `Router` in `app.js`:

```
//app.js
const rootRoute = {
  component: App,
  childRoutes: createRoutes(store),
};

const authRoute = {
  path: '/auth',
  component: Auth,
  childRoutes: authRoutes(store),
};

const routes = {
  childRoutes: [rootRoute, authRoute],
};
```

When I try to edit the default of `sagas.js` to:

```
export default function* root() {
  yield [
    defaultSaga(),
  ];
}
```

I get an error **`injectAsyncSagas: Expected "sagas" to be an array of generator functions`**. So what I did was to wrap `sagas.default` in the new route in an array:

```
//routes.js - authRoutes(store)
importModules.then(([reducer, sagas, component]) => {
  injectReducer('login', reducer.default);
  injectSagas([sagas.default]);
  renderRoute(component);
});
```

Why am I getting those errors and how can I fix them? (I'm quite new to React and Generators.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops. I forgot I called `store.runSaga(mySagas)` in `store.js` when I was testing which accepts an array of generator functions. I removed it and the error disappeared.